# How do I UnitTest my Website?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, web, visual-studio-2012

Sorry to ask such a simple question. I am a newbie.
I am setting up my website. I try to create a UnitTest Project for it, but I simply cannot not create a reference for it. Even though I have created a namespace for my class method, Visual Studio doesn't allow me to use the method and to see the namespace at all. 
Is UnitTesting website completely different from UnitTesting normal programs?
Any reference online available?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider using the new Fakes support in the Visual Studio 2012. In short, you can detour the call to the web site API and let the call routed to your supplied delegate. This allows you to isolate testing your code in a modualized fashion.

You can find more detail at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx

Regards,

Patrick Tseng

Visual Studio ALM team.

Answer (score 1):

use [this](http://kakimotonline.com/2011/02/13/tdd-in-asp-net-mvc-applications-with-moq-framework/) article.if u are user mvc use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818207/how-should-one-unit-test-a-net-mvc-controller) question.and this  stie

You've probably heard the old adage, "Better, faster, cheaper, pick any two." If you want something good and fast, it isn't going to be cheap, and if you want something fast and cheap, it isn't going to be very good. Cheaper, faster, and better means that we need to write more code more quickly, right? If only it were that simple. Learning to type faster might satisfy two of the requirements, but it isn't going to make the software you develop any better. So how do we make software better? What does "better" mean?

"Better" means producing flexible, maintainable software with a low number of defects; better software is all about long-term maintainability. To achieve this, a key design decision is to ensure that components are loosely coupled. Loosely coupled software has many benefits. One that stands out is that it improves our ability to test solutions. If we write software that can be broken down easily into small parts, it becomes easier to test. It sounds simple when you word it that way, but the amount of software in use today that is difficult to test or maintain shows that it is not as straightforward as we might like to think. Software needs to be coupled to do anything useful, but developers need tools and techniques to decrease coupling so that solutions are easier to test.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your website code is in one project, and your unit test code is in another project in the same solution? In order for code in one project to access the code of another project, you have to add a reference to the other project:

1. Right-click on the unit test project and click 'Add Reference...'
2. Open the 'Projects' tab, select the website project and click 'OK'.

Answer (score 0):

You should not unit test your website. You should unit test your business layer code. Testing your website would probably be UI testing, you can use tools for this like Selenium. I would recommend reading up on unit testing, and unit testing frameworks (MSTest, NUnit etc). You should layer your application so you can test your classes, objects, data access etc, all in absolute isolation.

Example:

A `Manage Users` page may show an administrator a list of all the users, filtered by a filter criteria.

The page should only handle the UI side of the problem, as in, it should only be concerned about *displaying* the data. It should send off a request to another object to get a list of users. Maybe something like a `UserRepository` which has a method called `GetUsers` which takes in a filter criteria.

This is where unit testing comes in. You would test (by mocking, perhaps) that when given a *very specific* list of users in the database, and a certain filter criteria, that the `GetUsers` method returns the list of users you expect.