# Integration tests - what would you test for in this controller?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit, integration-testing

I'm applying `NUnit` integration tests on our controller endpoints in a `.NET Web API 2` project whose models and controllers are generated via `Entity` `code first from database`.

I'm having trouble thinking of what parts of the controller I should test. **In the end, we'd just like to be able to automate *"can a user with "x" role get this data?"***

Looking in the `GET` portion of this controller, what parts would you test and what's your reasoning?

```
namespace api.Controllers.myNamespace
{

    public class myController : ApiController
    {
        private string strUserName;
        private string strError = "";
        private string strApiName = "myTable";
        private myDatabase db = new myDatabase();

        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------

        // GET: api/path
        public IQueryable<myTable> GetmyTable()
        {
            try
            {
                this.strUserName = this.getUserName();

                if
                (
                    // ----- authorize -----
                    db.view_jnc_role_api_permission.Count
                    (
                        view =>
                        (
                            view.permission == "get"
                            && view.apiName == this.strApiName
                            && view.userName == this.strUserName
                        )
                    ) == 1
                // ----- /authorize -----
                )
                {
                    // ----- get -----
                    IQueryable<myTable> data =

                    from tbl in db.myTable

                    where tbl.deleted == null

                    select tbl;
                    // ----- /get -----

                    return data;
                }
                else
                {
                    strError = "Unauthorized.";
                    throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (strError.Length == 0)
                {
                    if (this.showException())
                    {
                        strError = ex.ToString();
                    }
                }

                throw new HttpResponseException(ControllerContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, strError));
            }
        }

}
```

For reference, here's what I have so far. Some of these private fields I'm defining shouldn't be here - currently trying to get access to private methods from my test project via `AssemblyInfo.cs` to fix this:

```
namespace api.myNamespace
{
        [TestFixture]
        public class myController : ApiController
        {
            private string strUserName;
            private string strError = "";
            private string strApiName = "myTable";
            private myDb db = new myDb();
            // Using TransactionScope to (hopefully) prevent integration test's changes to database from persisting
            protected TransactionScope TransactionScope;
            // Instantiate _controller field
            private myController _controller;

            [SetUp]
            public void SetUp() {
                TransactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew);
                // It's possible that one test may leave some state which could impact subsequent tests - so we must reinstantiate _controller at the start of each new test:
                _controller = new myController();
            }

            [TearDown]
            public void TearDown()
            {
                TransactionScope.Dispose();
            }



            **//------ TESTS -------//
            // CanSetAndGetUserName
            // AuthorizedUserCanGetData
            // UnauthorizedUserCannotGetData
            // AuthorizedUserCanPutData
            // UnauthorizedUserCannotPutData
            // AuthorizedUserCanPostData
            // UnauthorizedUserCannotPostData
            // AuthorizedUserCanDeleteData
            // UnauthorizedUserCannotDeleteData**

            [Test]
            public void CanGetAndSetUsername()
            {
            // ARRANGE
            var user = _controller.getUserName();

            // ACT

            // ASSERT
            Assert.That(user, Is.EqualTo("my-internal-username"));
            }

        [Test]
        public void UnauthorizedUserCannotGetData()
        {
            var user = "Mr Unauthorized";
            // Unfinished bc integration testing is super abstract, subjective, hard, time consuming and hard. All downvoters are plebs.
            Assert.That(user, Is.EqualTo());

        }
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: answer to this was accepted here by the OP https://stackoverflow.com/a/31805380/1501191

Answer (score 1):

integration tests means several things:

1. you setup your test data in the database, via a script for example.
2. you call the endpoint under test knowing exactly what data you should call it with and what you should get. This is all based on your test data you setup in step 1.
3. you compare your expected data with the one you got back.

this is an integration test as it touches everything, both api and database.

Now, you said you are having trouble deciding which parts of the controller to test. This suggests you are confusing integration tests with unit tests.

Integration tests we already covered. 
Unit tests cover parts of functionality. You do not test controllers, forget about that.

What you really need to consider doing is this:

First, separate your code from the controller. Keep the controller very basic. It receives a call, validates the request model and passes it further to a class library where the functionality happens. This allows you to forget "testing the controller" and focus on your functionality instead. Unit tests will help here and your test cases will become something like this

1. I have a user, set up in a certain way.
2. I have some data, set up in a certain way
3. When I call method X, then I should get this response.

With such a setup in place, you can set your test data any way you like and check every single test case.

The only reason you wonder how you test your controller is because you dumped all your code into it, which of course makes everything hard. Think SOLID, think SOC ( Separation of concerns ).

One piece of advice: never ever return IQueryable from an endpoint, that's not data, that simply a query that hasn't run yet. Return a List, IEnumerable, an singular object, whatever you need, just make sure you execute that first by calling ToList() for example on your IQueryable expression first.

So, the steps are like this:

1. Setup your IQueryable first
2. Execute it by calling ToList(), First(), FirstOrDefault() whatever is appropriate and return the result of that.

Comment: Thanks for this reply! I have a lot of consideration to do...we have a small number of devs for this project. Integration testing could add a lot of time to this project that we don't have (esp considering that none of us has done it before and integration test documentation is sparse on the web). Even after all that - our tests may still be 'dishonest' and poorly written and will have to be repeatedly changed as our knowledge matures. For our specific case, maybe it's not feasable :(. FYI our controller was auto generated by Entity. I'll look further into your IQueryable advice regardless

Comment: you can start simple, for unit tests start testing functionality which changes data in some controlled way. You don't have to do too much. Writing tests teaches you one very important thing : how to write testable code, that's the main thing really.