# Unit Test For the Controller class

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, xunit

Hi I am trying to write a simple unit test for a function.

That function is to get something from the Controller class and get a specific item from it.

This is the code that I wanted to do unit test from (In Helper class):

```
public static string GetMemberCode(Controller controller)
{
    var claim = controller.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "membercode");
    return (claim != null) ? claim.Value : string.Empty;
}
```

The way this function is called is by using (More than 1 Controller class will be calling this)

```
string membercode = Helper.GetMemberCode(this)
```

This is what I have in my unit testing for now

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("asdfqwer")]
public void GetMemberCode_IfControllerIsValid(string membercode)
{
    //Arrange
    var controller = new Controller(); //ERROR:CS0144 Cannot create an instance of the abstract type or interface 'Controller'
    //TODO: How to assign value inside?
    //Act
    var result = Helper.GetMemberCode(controller);
    //Assert
    result.Should().Be(membercode);
}
```

So my question is How to assign value inside the Controller class?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your controller really the same name as its base class "Controller"? If so, you need the full namespace.

Comment: My controller is MemberController : Controller
While getting it its just string membercode = GetMemberCode(this)

Comment: The compiler error is because you are trying to instantiate the base abstract Controller class.

Comment: is there any other way to do unit test on this? And how do i assign the value inside the Controller.User.Claims ?

Comment: `var controller = new MemberController();` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: I cant do this method as due to this function is in a Helper class, and there are more than 1 controller will be calling this Helper class

Comment: I don't understand, you can pass the instance of MemberController to your helper function as it is a Controller. Have you seen the answers here discussing controller testing? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818207/how-should-one-unit-test-a-net-mvc-controller

Comment: I have go thru the discussions but then I am not allowed to change the code in the Helper class, I just need to create unit testing for the helper class. I am unable to declare the Controller to MemberController as due to not just MemberController will be using it, AController, BController, CController will also be calling that Helper class function.